# Woocomerce woocommerce_product_query meta_query keys

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to create a custom shop filter and I'd like to filter all the post that have a certain description (passed in a url query parameter).
I am using the woocommerce_product_query hook and i have the code like that

```
$meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query' );
$meta_query[] = array(
    'key' => '_description',
    'value' => $description,
    'compare' => 'LIKE',
);
```

I have also tried to put `_post_excerpt` instead of `_description` but the filter does not work, I get no products filtered out.

How can I fix this problem, I am pretty sure the problem is in the key because doing the same exact thing but with the price (with key `_price`) everything goes as intended

Comment: Do you filter price before description ? By description you mean the content or excertp of the product or custom field ? If you filter by multiple parameters maybe the problem is somewhere else ?

Comment: I have also tried to remove the price filter because I thought that might the problem but it still does not work. By the description I mean the description you see when you create a product in WooCommerce.